# Nested for loops start at wrong numbers

Tags: node.js, typescript, for-loop, nested, electron

I am trying to use a nested `for` loop to create x and y coordinates for a method call. However, `console.log` shows that the loop variables are starting at the wrong value. Why is this? Here is my code:

```
for(let x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    console.log(x);
    for(let y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
        console.log(y);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
34
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
[values 9 - 30 omitted]
31
34
1
```

...and so on

Comment: Are you sure the earlier values aren't just falling off the end of the console. It looks like you aren't seeing all the output.

Comment: Pretty sure your output is being clipped because it's to big.  Put `console.log('x: ' + x);` && `console.log('y' + y);`

Comment: I scrolled all the way up on the JS console in Electron's devtools before I copied the output to this question.

Comment: Do the following, and you will see that the output is correct: `node index.js > out.log`. Your terminal can't handle all that output, so you can't see all of it, but it's working fine.

Comment: Marcos Casagrande Thanks! It worked after all!

Comment: unfortunately i think this question is more likely to confuse other people rather then help them.

Comment: Why would you think that, Matt? One might argue that, if this happens to one person it is likely happen (and confuse) many others new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? I have tested this with node v8.9.1 and the code works for me as expected:

- The outer loop starts at index 0 which gets printed on the console,
- then the inner loop prints numbers 0 to 31.
- In turn the outer loop continues at index 1 which gets printed on console and
- then the inner loop prints 0 to 31,
- and so on

May be you got confused with the output at some point. Thus, my suggestion is to prefix the console outputs with x and y as shown below.

```
for(let x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    console.log('x=' + x);
    for(let y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
        console.log('y=' + y);
    }
}
```

You can also trial this on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@mwittig/Dump-Coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you with relative confidence that the behaviour your print is describing is not the behaviour a for-loop of the kind you've written will yield.

In fact, copy-pasting your exact code to the Chrome console (which runs V8, the same as node) will yield the correct result:

[image]

Your issue lies either elsewhere in your code or in the tool you're looking at the logging in.